# How to keep the previous version live while doing a scheduled publishing in wagtail?

Tags: django, content-management-system, wagtail

In wagtail if I have a page that's already live, and I edit this page and do a scheduled publishing in a later time it seems that this page will go down until the scheduled time comes. I wonder if it's possible in wagtail to keep the page live while do a schedule publishing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, Wagtail does not support that workflow.  The general consensus is that one would save the draft and manually hit publish (or create some custom scheduler to automate) when the update needs to go live.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wonder how to automate the publish process I'm kinda stuck there because wagtail doesn't provide a command to publish the draft on server side and the only way is to hit the publish button on the web page